# How to do add active class on click in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to change active class in li click

```
<pre> <li class="en active" (click)="useLanguage('fr')"></li>
                    <li class="sp" (click)="useLanguage('zh')"></li>
                    <li class="po" (click)="useLanguage('en')"></li>
```

In component I have written the function

```
useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
}
```

I want to add the active class when click on li also have to removed from other li. How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class can be conditionally applied using this syntax:

```html
<div [class.className]="someBoolean"><div>
```

So, if you store the selected language in a variable, you can do like this:

Template:

```js
  <li [class.active]="selectedLanguage==='fr'" (click)="useLanguage('fr')"></li>
  <li [class.active]="selectedLanguage==='zh'" (click)="useLanguage('zh')"></li>
  <li [class.active]="selectedLanguage==='en'" (click)="useLanguage('en')"></li>
```

Component:

```js
selectedLanguage = 'fr';

useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.selectedLanguage = language;
}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69778391?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) demo.

Answer (score 1):

// default lang

```
selectedLanguage = "fr";
```

// html

```
<li [ngClass]="{'selected-value' : selectedLanguage==='fr'}"(click)="useLanguage('fr')"></li>
```

// change language function

```
useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.selectedLanguage = language;
}
```